# Cannot install cabal-dev in windows

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Yeah... I give up:

```
PS D:\Projects\yesod\webapp> cabal install cabal-dev --force-reinstalls
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
haskell-platform-2012.2.0.0
Continuing even though the plan contains dangerous reinstalls.
Configuring network-2.3.0.14...
cabal.exe: The package has a './configure' script. This requires a Unix
compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
HTTP-4000.2.3 depends on network-2.3.0.14 which failed to install.
cabal-dev-0.9.1 depends on network-2.3.0.14 which failed to install.
network-2.3.0.14 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

P.S.: I am using Haskell platform btw.

Comment: "The package has a './configure' script. This requires a Unix
compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin." <- Have you one?

Comment: I'm not a windows user but recall there are some quick how-tos covering installing the `network` package on windows.  Just search around a little.

Comment: @DanielFischer No, but why should I install those on my windows box? They are not specified as "requirements" for Haskell platform.

Comment: P.S.: I am using Haskell platform btw.

Comment: They're not necessary for the platform, but installing packages with `./configure` scripts is cumbersome at best without one. `cabal-install` says it needs one to install packages with `./configure` scripts, so it might be a good idea to install one.

Comment: A Unix-like environment is not necessary to use the Haskell Platform. However, this fact is irrelevant, since you are attempting to install something that is not in the Platform.

Answer (score 2):

It's problem with package itself. There is [pull request](https://github.com/creswick/cabal-dev/pull/55) to fix this.

You can grab cabal-dev archive from [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cabal-dev/0.9.1/cabal-dev-0.9.1.tar.gz), unpack it and fix the .cabal file yourself.

Comment: Looks like it's merged? So can I just install it from that git repo?

Comment: Yup, but keep in mind that it might not be release quality. That's why i recommended you to download release tarball and patch it.